# Different results between hyperparameter optimisation and actual training/val values

Tags: machine-learning, deep-learning, hyperparameter-tuning, hyperparameter

If I want to do a hyperparameter optimisation on a dataset using e.g. hyperband or random search, I note that some of the models being randomly chosen seem to have rather good R2 scores, MSE etc.

I then get excited and create a neural network of the same description and train it on the same thing, same number of epochs, all seemingly same way etc. and I get quite a bit worse values.

Is there any good reason for this behaviour (e.g. are randomly chosen weights to start off that important for the final output? (???)) (and if this is true what causes might there be for this that explains it as "expected behaviour"?), or is it entirely unexpected and I should be thinking I've done something wrong? (and if this is true, what causes might there be?)

Thanks!

---

Edit: code layout

```
#build hypermodel 
class MyHyperModel(kt.HyperModel): 
  def build_model(self, hp): model = Sequential() ... 
  #do hyperband search 
  tuner = kt.tuners.Hyperband( MyHyperModel().build_model, objective='loss', ...) 
  tuner.search(x=X_train, y=y_train, epochs=...) 
  #get best 
  best_model = tuner.get_best_models(num_models=1) 
  #build best model and fit - same data 
  best_model.fit(x=X_train, y=y_train, epochs=...)
```

Answer (score 1):

Imho the most likely option is overfitting.

Hyper-parameter tuning is a kind of training, in the sense that we try to find the values which give the best results on a particular dataset. Like any training process overfitting can happen, and it's more likely to happen if the dataset is not representative enough (in particular too small), or if there are too many possible combinations of parameters.

Basically if one tries "too hard" to find the best hyper-parameters, then one is more likely to end up with hyper-parameters values which just happen to work by chance on this dataset.

Comment: Ah thanks. I mean that if I literally replicate the hyperparameter optimisation training, I get a different result. I.e. rather than train on a different dataset/check a score to one which it hasn't seen, I mean that the scores for training (and then checking validation score) on the same two datasets are different if hyperband/random hyperparameter optimisation is doing the training (and finding the best hyperparams) or if I manually use those best hyperparams myself, to that same data. I.e. in my mind the same models, same data, different scores.

Comment: @Socorro Do you mean that the dataset is exactly the same, as in exactly the same set of instances? i.e. not even a random splitting? In my hypothesis I was assuming that the second training is not applied to exactly the same subset of data.

Comment: Yes. Here's my overview of code:

#build hypermodel
class MyHyperModel(kt.HyperModel):
  def build_model(self, hp):             
    model = Sequential()
    ...

#do hyperband search
tuner = kt.tuners.Hyperband(
  MyHyperModel().build_model, objective='loss', ...)
tuner.search(x=X_train, y=y_train, epochs=...)     

#get best
best_model = tuner.get_best_models(num_models=1)
#build best model and fit - same data
best_model.fit(x=X_train, y=y_train, epochs=...)

The R2 values the model achieved, same data, in tuner.search aren't loosely the same as .fit. MSE's are more robust.

Comment: Layout of the code above isn't as good as it could be ... apologies for that.

Comment: @Socorro hope you don't mind: I copied the code inside the question, more readable this way.

Comment: @Socorro ok I see, so it's not overfitting related to the instances but it's something which is closely related to overfitting anyway. It would be interesting to cross-validate (even with only 3 or 5 folds): as far as i understand there's some instability in the choice of the hyper-parameters, so it's likely that CV would show a high variance across folds at least with these parameters, but maybe even without tuning. I think this would be an indication that the model is too complex for the data somehow.

Comment: Hi Erwan, I think actually it may be something to do with how Keras' backend computes R2 scores based on computing batch sizes (which still doesn't quite make sense), however, I have noticed extraordinary difference from using an R2 score reported in each training step vs. at the end separately from the training, and an enormous sensitivity of that in-training R2 score based on batch size in general. Perhaps this will be of use to someone else, but I still haven't resolved it precisely, but this is my best guess so far after some review now. And thanks for your advice.